# iPhone - do not receive significant location changes in iphone 3gs with iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, geolocation, iphone-3gs

I am trying to execute the following code on my iPhone 3gs, with the OS version as iOS 4.2.1

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
    [m_coreLocationMan startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
#endif
```

It somehow does not work for me. It works on my iPhone 4, but not on iPhone 3gs with iOS4. Does anyone have any insight into the problem?

Comment: Are Location services on? Is it marked as an allowed app in Settings.app?

Comment: yes, those were the first things I checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the return value of `+[CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]`. If that says `YES` on the problem device but you're still not getting any messages, then you have a problem; otherwise, it's the expected behavior.